# Simplifying this complex logical expression

Tags: python

Do you know how I can simplify this logical expression?
I am trying to fix it for hours, but I can't.

```
if (trade_dur == 0 and (
    (
        is_short
        # Red candle (for longs)
        and row[OPEN_IDX] < row[CLOSE_IDX]  # Red candle
        and trade.open_rate > row[OPEN_IDX]  # trade-open above open_rate
        and close_rate < row[CLOSE_IDX]  # closes below close
    )
    or
    (
        not is_short
        # green candle (for shorts)
        and row[OPEN_IDX] > row[CLOSE_IDX]  # green candle
        and trade.open_rate < row[OPEN_IDX]  # trade-open below open_rate
        and close_rate > row[CLOSE_IDX]  # closes above close
     )
)):
```

Comment: Does it matter what happens in the cases where `row[OPEN_IDX] == row[CLOSE_IDX]`, `trade.open_rate == row[OPEN_IDX]`, and/or `close_rate == row[CLOSE_IDX]`?

Comment: Yes, because it's a backtesting script for an open-source trading bot, using this logical expression algorithm can understand whether portofolio went up or down.
Open and close numbers can't be the same you see.

Comment: whenever I have a large expression that could be simplified, I apply the rules of boolean algebra to the expression and minimize it that way. 

This is not necessarily a huge expression but you can still minimize it using boolean algebra.

Comment: I went through several online boolean algebra simplifier and none of them could find a better form for (A * B * C * D)+(~A*~B*~C*~D). I would still do something similar to what @Ni2Be proposed to make the whole thing more readable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a function, you could use an early return like:

```
if(trade_dur != 0):
  return
```

You could then define some bools with appropriate names to make it more readable:

```
  is_red = row[OPEN_IDX] < row[CLOSE_IDX]
  trade_open_above = trade.open_rate > row[OPEN_IDX]
  closes_below = trade.open_rate > row[OPEN_IDX]
    :
  is_tradable = (is_short and is_red and trade_open_above and closes_below)
             or (not is_short and is_green and trade_open_below and closes_above )

  if(is_tradable) : ...
```

Comment: it looks all the booleans on the first halve are just negated on the second so I would personally prefer
(is_short and is_red and trade_open_above and closes_below) or (not is_short and not is_red and not trade_open_above and not trade closes_below)  but I admit it's largely a matter of taste.